# selecting a row from angular ui-grid using protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor, angular-ui-grid

i'm trying to automate an application with Ui grid. I need to select a row from grid and proceed the test. I have written the code in jasmine and it is showing an error in console..

My spec file code

```
it("Angular ui Grid",function(){
browser.driver.sleep(5000);
var gridTestUtils = require('./lib/gridTestUtils.spec.js'); 

gridTestUtils.clickGridMenuItem('grid1', 2);

browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        // element(by.id('viewReqBtn')).click();
        // element(by.css('[ng-click="adhocUploadFunc()"]')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(100);  

    });
```

I have included gridTestUtils.spec.js from github, but something is missing in my code. I'm new to protractor , have learned basics from youTube tutorial videos

UI-grid

```js
<div ui-i18n="en" class="grid stmt-request-grid-1 ui-grid ng-isolate-scope grid1496803698369" style="width: 100%;" id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection="" ui-grid-auto-resize="" ui-grid-move-columns="" ui-grid-resize-columns="" ng-show="dataLoaded" aria-hidden="false">
```

[error message displayed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDjpN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the gridTestUtils. See [this page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.e2eTestLibrary.api:gridTest) for more documentation.

I guess you would need to address: `var elmt = gridTestUtils.dataCell('grid1', <row>, <col>);`

and then click on the result: `gridTestUtils.click(elmt);`